# How can I refine a linq query that binds to a DTO via another list?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing some SalesForce work via C# and I have a list of Cases. You should not need to be familiar with SalesForce to understand what the issue is. I'm trying to retrieve a list of CaseComment objects where the parentId of CaseComment matches the Id of Case. i.e:

**Case 1** 
Id = 123456

**Case Comment 1**
Id = 5532094
ParentId = 234242

**Case Comment 2**
Id = 984984
ParentId = 123456

In this case, the parentId of case comment 2 matches Case 1 and thus should be returned. Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
    static List<SalesForceCaseComment> GetCaseCommentsFromListOfCases(List<SalesForceCase> Cases)
    {
        using (salesforce_backupsEntities le = new salesforce_backupsEntities())
        {
            List<SalesForceCaseComment> casecomments = (from c in le.CaseComments select new SalesForceCaseComment
                                                            {
                                                                CommentBody = c.CommentBody,
                                                                CreatedById = c.CreatedById,
                                                                Id = c.Id,
                                                                IsDeleted = c.IsDeleted,
                                                                IsPublished = c.IsPublished,
                                                                LastModifiedById = c.LastModifiedById,
                                                                ParentId = c.ParentId
                                                            }).Where(n => Cases.Any(s=> s.Id == n.ParentId)).ToList();
            return casecomments;              
        }
    }
```

This unfortunately results in the following error:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'DTO.SalesForceCase'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're effectively joining a local `List<SalesForceCase>` to a table on the provider side, which probably isn't going to work. If the provider supports the `Contains` operator, you can do this:

```
var ids = Cases.Select(c => c.Id).ToArray();
var comments = from c in le.CaseComments
               where ids.Contains(c.ParentId)
               select new /* projection */;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means that underline provider doesnt support enumeration types, so you need to either write your own visitor to enumerate it (harder) or just convert it to expression with primitive types with "or", which simply means looping through your array and adding conditions.

Second way could be easier if salesforce_backupsEntities inherited from ObjectContext. In this case you can use `IN` esql operator.

Also, if there is navigation property in Case object, you may want to attach object to context and do load on navigation property ( `case.Comments.Load()` )

Answer (score 0):

I would guess something like this should work (join instead of Where):

```
  static List<SalesForceCaseComment> GetCaseCommentsFromListOfCases(List<SalesForceCase> Cases)
{
    using (salesforce_backupsEntities le = new salesforce_backupsEntities())
    {
        List<SalesForceCaseComment> casecomments = (from c in le.CaseComments 
where Cases.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(c.ParentId)
select new SalesForceCaseComment
                                                        {
                                                            CommentBody = c.CommentBody,
                                                            CreatedById = c.CreatedById,
                                                            Id = c.Id,
                                                            IsDeleted = c.IsDeleted,
                                                            IsPublished = c.IsPublished,
                                                            LastModifiedById = c.LastModifiedById,
                                                            ParentId = c.ParentId
                                                        })).ToList();
        return casecomments;              
    }
}
```

Comment: just rename case variable in join to oCase etc, otherwise it won't even compile

Comment: Good point. I suppose @ would have worked too, but I took your suggestion.

Comment: yeah just anything to not match keyword.

Comment: Oddly enough, this results in the same error. But it made sense to me. :(